# Augmentation in Computer Science

Tags: meaning, computing

How would you define augmentation in terms of Computer Science?

I've heard it used as ‘[strengthening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542?noredirect=1#comment29088343_15012542)’:

> “In jQuery, you design a page, and then you make it dynamic. This is because jQuery was designed for augmentation...)”

or as ‘[extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17941758/327074)’:

> “I heard about cases where adding an extra requirement to a binary search (for example) can be called augmentation.”

A Google search for ‘[augmentation computer science](https://www.google.com/search?q=augmentation+computer+science)’ brings up a Stack Overflow question, but that's for quite a specific context. Wikipedia defines Augmentation for numerous disciplines but not for Computer Science.

There are lots of examples if you [search for augmentation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=augmentation) on programmers.SE. I had asked this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/215770/27956) on programmers.SE - but was pointed here instead.

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you're looking for? It doesn't sound like you're looking for the definition of a computer science term (which would be off-topic here), but I'm not sure what you are actually looking for.

Comment: Could you give an example in a sentence?

Comment: I am not sure how much we can help you aside from either a standard dictionary definition or the specifics noted at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmentation).

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner I've put in the two sentences I was referring to in the links. Also if you do a [search for 'augmentation' on programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=augmentation) you get hundreds of sentences

Comment: I'm not convinced that you've correctly understood your first example. It seems to me that the use there is *extension*, and that the parenthetical mention of *strengthening* was an aside, unrelated to the meaning in the referenced sentence. And if it *does* mean *strengthening* then that is anyway a special case of *extension*, merely narrowing the purpose of the extension.

Comment: @PeterTaylor - the person who made the quote referred to it as 'strengthening' himself in a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542?noredirect=1#comment29088343_15012542) when I asked him. What you're saying makes sense - most programmers seem to be talking about extending something.

Comment: You've missed my point. He mentioned strengthening in brackets and after the initials *PS*. That suggests that he said it that as a piece of interesting trivia rather than as an explanation of what he meant when he used *augmentation* earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Augmentation means the same thing in computer science as it does in general English, which I would summarise as: extending something to make it better.

Oxford Dictionaries Online gives this [definition for the verb *augment*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/augment):

> Pronunciation: /ɔːgˈmɛnt/
>
> - make (something) greater by adding to it; increase

There are some particular uses of *augment* which have become terms in their own right and imply a more specific meaning based on the general one; for example, [*augmented reality*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality), [*augmenting path*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AugmentingPath.html), [*graph augmentation*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=899317), [*augmented data structure*](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~hagha/topic20/topic20.html).

In the context of a particular sub-field (for example, graph theory) or even a particular algorithm, the term *augmentation* may take on a more specialised and well-defined meaning, but in computer science as a whole, the meaning of *augmentation* is not specialised.

Answer (score -1):

The correct term  you are looking for is **Augmented Reality**. It is related to computer science.

In general it means, *Something which is physical, which is real is brought down to your computer or to your mobile*.

one simple example: the whole map of the world can be brought down to your mobile, google maps.. as such...

for more examples, if you google augmented reality you will find a whole lot of explanations. It is exactly what you wanted to know. One of the pinnacles of modern world.

Comment: 1. 'Augmented Reality' is but *one instance* of augmentation. 2. Your understanding of AR is not correct, please look up the definition of the term and its explanation, online.

Comment: @Kris 1. Accepted. 2. Dear Kris your understanding of AR is not correct as pointed by John. 3. I am a software engineer and right now, I am working in a AR project for my company's innovation lab. May be i dint explain it in detail, but thats a job to be done in stackoverflow.com.... for few more examples, something like Nokia City Lens, is a beautiful example of augmented reality.

Comment: Please see my comment @John.

Answer (score -1):

See [Intelligence Amplification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_amplification) and

[Augmented reality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality)

on Wikipedia.

In the field of computer science in general, *augmentation* deals with aspects of connectivity and responsiveness, while *simulation* deals with replication and separation.

Comment: I don't agree with your final sentence. Augmentation doesn't have anything to do with connectivity or responsiveness. It means basically the same thing in computer science as it does in general English: extending something to make it better. The two uses I'm most familiar with: Augmented reality takes reality and augments it with extra information. An augmented data structure is (typically) a well known data structure which has been extended with some extra information so it can solve a new (but related) problem.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew We are familiar enough with the things over here. The final sentence is based on solid facts. That said, Augmented Reality & Augmented Data Structures are not 'two uses'. They are not related to each other in any way. It's better not to confuse yourself, and mislead others in the process.

Comment: They are two uses of the word "augmentation" in computer science, which is what the question asks about.

Comment: If you think I'm wrong, perhaps you could *expand your answer* instead of just dismissing my comment out of hand.

Comment: @kris: Could you please point out those solid facts? I hope your facts will have some source and not based on your  assumptions.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew Remember this is ELU. For technical aspects of the terms, you can ask a separate question on the relevant tech site. Please avoid extended discussions in comments.

Comment: @uma See my comment at John.

Comment: @Kris: I will be plain: I believe your answer is unclear, incomplete and possibly incorrect. The comment system exists at least partly to allow incomplete or incorrect answers to be improved via discussion, and I would appreciate it if you made an attempt to engage in that process rather than stonewalling. As to your response: I have no idea how you expect to answer a question about the meaning of augmentation in computer science *without* any reference to technical aspects. If you believe the question itself is inappropriate for ELU, you should vote to close the question.

Comment: @Kris: To avoid the need for extended discussion, I have added a separate answer. I apologise if my comments here have been overly antagonistic. If you think *my* answer is incomplete, I would be happy for you to comment on it.